# Comparar dos array char java(usar isDigit sin usar isDigit)

Tags: java, char

Quisiera comparar los dos array char, ya intente con if y poniendo "==", pero marca error

```
public void digito(){
      char[] nums = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
      System.out.println("Ingrese una palabra");
      ref.pal2 = leer.nextLine();
      char[] arr3 = ref.pal2.toCharArray();
      
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa _"(usar isDigit sin usar isDigit)"_? ¿Qué exactamente estás buscando hacer porque tu código no tiene que ver mucho con la pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Para comparar dos Arrays de `chars` usa [`Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(char%5B%5D,%20char%5B%5D)) de  `java.util`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] arr1 = { 'x', 'y', 'b', 'a' };
        char[] arr2 = { 'x', 'y', 'b', 'a' };
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2));
    }
}
```